# Phaser 3: Show Interactable area

Tags: javascript, debugging, phaser-framework

The game I'm creating doesn't require any physics, however you are able to interact when hovering over/clicking on the sprite by using sprite.setInteractive({cursor: "pointer"});, sprite.on('pointermove', function(activePointer) {...}); and similar.

I ran into some issues with the interactive area and wanted to debug it by showing the "area" that is interactable. However I could only find ways to do that that are related to Arcade Physics. Is there any way to get something like a debug outline around my interactable area without Physics?

Comment: I think this question was duplicated by mistake https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266893/phaser-3-change-hitbox-interactive-area-of-sprite-without-physics

Comment: @winner_joiner It wasn't, although they are related (and the first paragraph is identical)! But they're technically two different topics, and I wasn't sure if I should put them together or seperate, since they require different sets of answers.

Comment: upsss, you are right.  sorry, I should have read the whole question. :) It happens. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Out-Of-The-Box***, without physics, I don't know any way, but one could get this function/feature with a *small* helper-function. *(but maybe there is something, since phaser is a really extensive framework. But I also couldn't find anything).*

Something like this, could do the trick, and is reuseable:

```
function debugSpriteArea(scene, sprite){
    let debugRect = scene.add.rectangle(
        sprite.x, sprite.y,
        sprite.displayWidth, sprite.displayHeight, 
        0xff0000).setOrigin(sprite.originX,
            sprite.originY);
    debugRect.setDepth(-1);
}
```

**Here the help-function in action:**

```js
let Scene = {
    preload ()
    {
        this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
    },

    create ()
    {
        // Animation set
        this.anims.create({
            key: 'walk',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }),
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        });

        const cody = this.add.sprite(200, 100, 'brawler')
            .setOrigin(0.5);

        debugSpriteArea(this, cody);

        cody.play('walk');
        cody.setInteractive();

        this.mytext =  this.add.text(10, 10, 'No Hit', { fontFamily: 'Arial' });

        cody.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
            let originXOffset = cody.displayWidth * cody.originX;
            let originYOffset = cody.displayHeight * cody.originY;

            let x = (pointer.x - cody.x + originXOffset ) / (cody.displayWidth / cody.width)
            let y = (pointer.y - cody.y + originYOffset) / (cody.displayHeight / cody.height);

            if(cody.anims && cody.anims.currentFrame){

                let currentFrame = cody.anims.currentFrame;
                let pixelColor = this.textures.getPixel(x, y, currentFrame.textureKey, currentFrame.textureFrame);

                if(pixelColor.a > 0) {
                    this.mytext.text = 'hit';
                } else {
                    this.mytext.text = 'No hit';
                }
            }
        }, this);
    }
};


function debugSpriteArea(scene, sprite){
    let debugRect = scene.add.rectangle(
        sprite.x, sprite.y,
        sprite.displayWidth, sprite.displayHeight, 
        0xff0000).setOrigin(sprite.originX,
                sprite.originY);
    debugRect.setDepth(-1);
}

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: Scene
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```